# Bit-shift behavior

Tags: c++, bit-shift

```c
uint16_t a = 0x00 << 8 + 0xB9;
printf("%d",a);
```

I'm expecting `185` as an output but I'm getting `0`.

What is happening here?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Comment: @tkausl Was just about to post the exact same link! Note: `+` has higher precedence than `<<` - so you are shifting `0x00` by `n` bits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) link, you'll see that the order of precedence means that the addition is performed before the shift. Change your code to

```
uint16_t a = (0x00 << 8) + 0xB9;
printf("%d",a);
```

to see the desired behaviour.